# How to deal with new pip3.x for each Python version

Tags: python, pip, package, version, upgrade

After recently upgrading from python 3.7 to 3.8, I realized that my packages installed on my system were not transferred over after installing 3.8. Specifically, I am seeing the below for pip3.7 list:

```
Package           Version  
----------------- ---------
appdirs           1.4.3    
astroid           2.3.3    
attrs             19.3.0   
click             7.1.1    
isort             4.3.21   
lazy-object-proxy 1.4.3    
mccabe            0.6.1    
pathspec          0.7.0    
pip               20.0.2   
pylint            2.4.4    
regex             2020.2.20
setuptools        46.0.0   
six               1.14.0   
toml              0.10.0   
typed-ast         1.4.1    
wheel             0.34.2   
wrapt             1.11.2
```

while pip3 or pip3.8 list shows:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.0.2
setuptools 41.2.0
```

Is this the expected behavior or did not do something wrong while upgrading to 3.8? If this is the expected behavior, how do you transfer the packages over to the new version? Is it not best practice to do so?

Comment: I believe it's expected behavior. Projects installed for one version of the Python interpreter are not usually compatible with another version. Only _maintenance versions_ are compatible with each other: `3.7.n` with `3.7.m`, and `3.8.x` with `3.8.y`.

Comment: Major Python versions are not ABI-compatible, so only pure-python packages would be reusable. To reinstall all deps, you can use smth like `pip3.7 list --user --format=freeze | xargs pip3.8 install --user`. Don't do that with system packages, though.